# Designing a phonebook menu bar, filter and sorting order buttons included

Tags: java, gui, javafx

I designed a phonebook application using JavaFX (trying to follow Material Design by Google, as you can see in the screenshot).
The code below is the code that handles the `ButtonBar` next to the search bar, but I'm new to JavaFX and I want to know if this is really poorly written and organized.

```
package gui;

import data.Contact;
import data.Database;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuButton;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.SeparatorMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import model.ContactListOrderManager;
import model.ListOrder;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ListButtonsController {
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<MenuButton> orderButton;
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<MenuButton> filterButton;
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<OrderButtonController> orderButtonController;
    private final SimpleObjectProperty<ObservableList<Contact>> contactList;

    public ListButtonsController(MenuButton orderButton, MenuButton filterButton,
                                 ObservableList<Contact> contactList) {
        this.orderButton = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(orderButton);
        this.filterButton = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(filterButton);
        var orderButtonControl = new OrderButtonController(this);
        this.orderButtonController = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(orderButtonControl);
        this.contactList = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(contactList);
    }

    protected MenuButton getOrderButton() {
        return orderButton.get();
    }

    protected MenuButton getFilterButton() {
        return filterButton.get();
    }

    private OrderButtonController getOrderButtonController() {
        return orderButtonController.get();
    }

    public ObservableList<Contact> getContactList() {
        return contactList.get();
    }

    public void listButtonsSetup() throws IOException {
        getOrderButtonController().orderButtonSetup();
        setButtonsStyle();
        setButtonsIcons();
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(getOrderButton(), 290d);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(getOrderButton(), 1.5);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(getFilterButton(), 240d);
        AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(getFilterButton(), 1.5);
    }

    private void setButtonsIcons() throws IOException {
        try (var filterInput = new FileInputStream("icons/filter_black_24dp.png");
             var orderInput = new FileInputStream("icons/sort_black_24dp.png")) {
            getOrderButton().setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(orderInput)));
            getFilterButton().setGraphic(new ImageView(new Image(filterInput)));
        }
    }

    private void setButtonsStyle() {
        getOrderButton().getStylesheets().add("file:stylesheets/menu-button.css");
        getOrderButton().getStyleClass().add("menu-button");
        getFilterButton().getStylesheets().add("file:stylesheets/menu-button.css");
        getFilterButton().getStyleClass().add("menu-button");
    }

}

class OrderButtonController {
    private final ListButtonsController generalController;
    private final MenuButton orderButton;

    protected OrderButtonController(ListButtonsController controller) {
        this.generalController = controller;
        this.orderButton = generalController.getOrderButton();
    }

    protected void orderButtonSetup() {
        var ordinatorGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        var alphabeticalOrderItem = new RadioMenuItem("Alphabetically");
        alphabeticalOrderItem.setSelected(true);
        ordinatorGroup.getToggles().add(alphabeticalOrderItem);
        var separator = new SeparatorMenuItem();
        var orderGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        var ascendingRadioItem = new RadioMenuItem("Ascending");
        ascendingRadioItem.setSelected(true);
        var descendingRadioItem = new RadioMenuItem("Descending");
        orderGroup.getToggles().addAll(ascendingRadioItem, descendingRadioItem);

        descendingRadioItem.setOnAction(actionEvent ->
                ContactListOrderManager.sortList(generalController.getContactList(),
                        ListOrder.getOrdering((RadioMenuItem) orderGroup.getSelectedToggle()),
                        descendingRadioItem.isSelected()));
        ascendingRadioItem.setOnAction(actionEvent ->
                ContactListOrderManager.sortList(generalController.getContactList(),
                        ListOrder.getOrdering((RadioMenuItem) orderGroup.getSelectedToggle()),
                        descendingRadioItem.isSelected()));
        alphabeticalOrderItem.setOnAction(actionEvent ->
                ContactListOrderManager.sortList(generalController.getContactList(),
                        ListOrder.ALPHABETIC, descendingRadioItem.isSelected()));

        setMenusStyle(alphabeticalOrderItem, ascendingRadioItem, descendingRadioItem);
        orderButton.getItems().addAll(alphabeticalOrderItem, separator, ascendingRadioItem, descendingRadioItem);
    }

    private void setMenusStyle(RadioMenuItem... menus) {
        for (RadioMenuItem menu : menus) {
            menu.getStyleClass().add("order-menu");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Where is the `FXML` file? Are you trying to create a custom node? Either way, I am not sure `SimpleObjectProperty<MenuButton> orderButton` using ObjectProperty in this manner is good. It should be `MenuButton orderButton`. I don't know if I truly understand what you are doing here and why.